# How to save emoji characters ( or ) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, utf8mb4

I want to save unicode characters in my db. But not all characters saves correctly.
How can I save  or ? (no problem with ☔️ ⛧ etc.)

Comment: Define "not saves correctly"

Comment: I see "?" instead  or  in Workbench

Comment: One question mark or 4?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored